# Snippet for creating folder + files in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

For React components, I find myself following the same steps every time:

1. Create a folder with the component name (`Heading`, for example)
2. Create a `Heading.js` file inside this folder
3. Create an adjacent `index.js` and `export * from './Heading'`
4. Create a `Heading.styles.js`, `import styled from 'styled-components'` and `export const Heading = styled.div` (`div` could be whatever is appropriate)
5. In `Heading.js` do something like this:

```
import * as S from "./Header.styles";

export function Header() {
  return <S.Header>Header</S.Header>;
}
```

6. Repeat each time I create a new component

Is there a way I can create some kind of 'folder snippet' to assist this process?

Comment: it look nice to have that feature! I don't think that VSCode have something like that now. I will considering to create a VSCode extension to solve this problem!

Comment: @TakashiAnji There is already an extension for that, search the market place.

Comment: Part of the problem can be solved with extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates), I will consider adding the possibility to name the new file based on the directory you create the file

Comment: thank for sharing ❤️

Comment: In v1.5.0 of extension **File Templates** you can now construct the new filename with the first line of the template

Comment: Nice, File Templates seems to be the answer here. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) (v1.5.0)

You are able to create global templates and specific templates for a project.

If you have a particular naming scheme that uses the directory name or workspace name you can add a special first line to construct the file name.

Template **Component.js**

```
##@@## ${relativeFileDirnameSplit[-1]}
import * as S from "./${relativeFileDirnameSplit[-1]}.styles";

export function ${relativeFileDirnameSplit[-1]}() {
  return <S.${relativeFileDirnameSplit[-1]}>${input:Component Header:}</S.${relativeFileDirnameSplit[-1]}>;
}
```

Template **index.js**

```
##@@## index
export * from './${relativeFileDirnameSplit[-1]}'
```

Template **Component.styles.js**

```
##@@## ${relativeFileDirnameSplit[-1]}.styles
import styled from 'styled-components'
export const ${relativeFileDirnameSplit[-1]} = styled.${input:Component styled tag:}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this extension [**Folder Templates**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Huuums.vscode-fast-folder-structure)